# Pydev configuration to specify generated variables

Tags: django, pydev

I am using Pydev with Django which marks Django generated variables as errors, eg `User.DoesNotExist`. In pylint I can specify a setting called generated variables. Is there such a setting in Pydev?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, go to window / preferences / pydev / editor / code analysis / undefined, add your variables to globals there.